# Java Function Analysis

Tags: java, for-loop

Okay..I am a total Python guy and have very rarely worked with Java and its methods. The condition is that I have a got a Java function that I have to explain to my instructor and I have got no clue about how to do so..so if one of you can read this properly, kindly help me out in breaking it down and explaining it. Also, i need to find out any flaw in its operation (i.e. usage of loops, etc.) if there is any. Finally, what is the difference between 'string' and 'string[]' types?

```
public static void search(String findfrom, String[] thething){
  if(thething.length > 5){
      System.err.println("The thing is quite long");
  }

  else{
      int[] rescount = new int[thething.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < thething.length; i++){
          String[] characs = findfrom.split("[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
          for(int j = 0; j < characs.length; j++){
              if(characs[j].compareTo(thething[i]) == 0){
                  rescount[i]++;
        }
    }
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < thething.length; j++) {
          System.out.println(thething[j] + ": " + rescount[j]);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Answering the "finally" question: String is an array of characters, String[] is an array of strings.

Comment: `dataType variableName` - defines single variable (variableName) of data type (dataType).  
`dataType[] variableName` - defines an array variable (variableName) of data type (dataType).  
Most of other code there is self explanatory - `thething.length` is length of thething. It will be easier if you go through the code yourself and say what exactly **you** don't understand (I am **NOT** familiar with Python, so don't know how different it is from Java).

Answer (score 1):

- 1st para: findfrom is a string, it is supposed to be `"[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]"` (regex) delimited.
- 2nd para: thething is a String array, it contains max 5 strings, 
  the method will find how many times the Strings in 'thething' in findfrom. and print the result out.

e.g.

```
findfrom="hello'there'happy'birthday'"
thething={"there","birthday","hello","birthday"}

result would be:
there: 1
birthday: 2
hello: 1
birthday: 2
```

btw, the line

```
String[] characs = findfrom.split("[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
```

may move out of the for-loop. since the findfrom is not changed, no need do split repeatly.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(thething.length > 5){
      System.err.println("The thing is quite long");
}
```

If the length of the `String[] thething` is greater than 5. Print an error..
If not do what is inside the following else block.

`else{`

```
int[] rescount = new int[thething.length];
```

Create a new array of `int`s with size equal to the length of the `String[] thething`

```
for(int i = 0; i < thething.length; i++)
```

For each index `i` the String[] thething.

```
String[] characs = findfrom.split("[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
```

Create a new String[] called characs that splits the String findfrom into several parts based on the regular expression `"[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]"`. The 0 means this pattern will be applied as many times as possible.

```
for(int j = 0; j < characs.length; j++){
```

Now for each index `j` in the String[] characs...

```
if(characs[j].compareTo(thething[i]) == 0){
```

Compare the String in the characs String[] at index `j` with String in thething String[] at index `i`.

If the two match i.e the `compareTo` method returns 0.

```
rescount[i]++;
```

Increments the `int` that is at index `i` in the `int[]` `rescount`.

```
  for (int j = 0; j < thething.length; j++) {
      System.out.println(thething[j] + ": " + rescount[j]);
  }
```

Finally for each index `j` in the `String[]` `thething` print out the String at that index and the `int` at that index in the `int[]` `rescount`

And also a `String` is an array of characters, Eg `String string = "word"` and a `String[]` is an array Strings. For example `String[] strings = new String[]{"word1", "word2",....}.`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        search(
            "you like me but do you \"like like\" me", 
            new String[]{"you", "like", "me", "not"}
        );
    }

    /**
     * Given a string of words (each word separated by one or more of the
     * following characters: tab, carriage return, newline, single quote, double
     * quote, a form feed, or a word boundary) count the occurrence of each
     * search term provided, with a 5 term limit.
     * 
     * @param findfrom
     *            the string of words
     * @param thething
     *            the search terms.  5 at most, or count will not be performed.
     */
    public static void search(String findfrom, String[] thething) {
        if (thething.length > 5) {
            System.err.println("The thing is quite long");
        }
        else {
            String[] characs = findfrom.split("[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
            int[] rescount = new int[thething.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < thething.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < characs.length; j++) {
                    if (characs[j].compareTo(thething[i]) == 0) {
                        rescount[i]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < thething.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(thething[j] + ": " + rescount[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
you: 2
like: 3
me: 2
not: 0
```

Comment: thanks joe...you see any flaw in this code? I mean anything that can be modified to enhance the functionality?

Comment: Nothing other than what Kent said, about moving that .split() outside of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

The **Python** version of that code would be something like this:

```
import sys
import re

def search(findfrom, thething):
  """Take a string and a list of strings. Printout each of the strings
in the list and a count of how many times that string appeared in the
input string. The string comparison will be based on the input string being
divided up into tokens. The delimiter for each token will be either a whitespace
character, a single quote, or a double quote. """
  if len(thething) > 5:
      sys.stderr.write("The thing is quite long")
  else:
      rescount = [0] * len(thething)
      for i in range(0,len(thething)):
          characs = re.split("[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", findfrom)
          for j in range(0,len(characs)):
              if characs[j] == thething[i]:
                  rescount[i] = rescount[i] + 1

      for j in range(0,len(thething)):
          print thething[j] + ": " + str(rescount[j])


string = 'you like me but do you "like like" me'
strings = ["you", "like", "me", "not"]
search(string,strings)
```

Outputs:

```
you: 2
like: 3
me: 2
not: 0
```